# TS2345 Argument of type void not assignable | React useState hook + promise

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-typescript

The full error: `TS2345: Argument of type 'void' is not assignable to parameter of type '((value: boolean) => boolean | PromiseLike<boolean>) | null | undefined'.`

The line in question is this one: `<button type="submit" onClick={() => auth.logout().then(setLoggedIn(false))}>`

And specifically TypeScript doesn't like the `setLoggedIn(false)` (that's what is highlighted in the IDE).

So the problem is when I use a **setMyState** `useState` hook in the `then()` part of a promise.  I know I defined my types wrong because I'm seeing an error, but this error has confused me; what is the `argument of type void`, because setLoggedIn takes a boolean.

My code:

**Main.tsx**

```
  const [isLoggedIn, setLoggedIn] = useState<boolean>(false);

  <UserLoginForm isLoggedIn={isLoggedIn} setLoggedIn={setLoggedIn} />
```

**UserLoginForm.tsx**

```
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';
import getAuthClient from '../utils/auth';

const auth = getAuthClient();

interface MyProps {
  isLoggedIn: boolean,
  setLoggedIn: React.Dispatch<React.SetStateAction<boolean>>,
}

const UserLoginForm: React.VFC<MyProps> = ({ isLoggedIn, setLoggedIn }: MyProps) => {

  if (isLoggedIn) {
    return (
      <div>
        <p>You are currently logged in.</p>
        <button type="submit" onClick={() => auth.logout().then(setLoggedIn(false))}>
          Log out
        </button>
      </div>
    );
  }
```

**auth.tsx**

```
  /**
   * Delete the stored OAuth token, effectively ending the user's session.
   */
  function logout(): Promise<boolean> {
    localStorage.removeItem(updatedConfig.token_name);
    return Promise.resolve(true);
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

You're calling `setLoggedIn` *immediately*. This:

```
<button type="submit" onClick={() => auth.logout().then(setLoggedIn(false))}>
```

is like doing

```
const parameterToPassToThen = setLoggedIn(false);
```

```
<button type="submit" onClick={() => auth.logout().then(parameterToPassToThen)}>
```

Which doesn't make sense.

Another example of the same problem, outside of React:

```js
const prom = new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, 2000));

console.log('starting');
prom.then(console.log('resolved'));

// `resolved` is printed immediately, not 2 seconds later
```

`.then` should always accept a *function* instead:

```
<button type="submit" onClick={() => auth.logout().then(() => { setLoggedIn(false); })}>
```